# copy a string of data from 1 cell in another worksheet down to the last row

Tags: excel, vba

Need help copy the same IDs from another worksheet to this worksheet to the last row.

So the code below is what I got so far and everything works perfectly. what I need now is to copy the ID down to last row with what the data that the macro already ran.

The code below is basically what i want but I want it to copy multiple time down to the last row and the the has to be dynamic

```
Set CopyRng3 = wsCopy.Range("B1")
      'Currency
CopyRng3.Copy
        wsDest.Range("B" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

 For Each Col In CopyColumns

      lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
      lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
      'Price Date
      Set copyrng = wsCopy.Range(Col & "30:" & Col & lCopyLastRow)
      'Price
      Set CopyRng2 = wsCopy.Range(copyrng(1, 1).Offset(0, 1), copyrng(copyrng.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(0, 1))
      'ID
      Set CopyRng3 = wsCopy.Range("B1")
      'Currency
      Set CopyRng4 = wsCopy.Range("C1")



        If copyrng.Find("#N/A", LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
        copyrng.Copy
        wsDest.Range("C" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        CopyRng2.Copy
        wsDest.Range("J" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        CopyRng3.Copy
        wsDest.Range("B" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        CopyRng4.Copy
        wsDest.Range("I" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

       End If

     Next Col


     For i = LoaderHeaderRow + 1 To lDestLastRow - 1
        'Action
        wsDest.Cells(i, RecAction) = "New"
        'Pricelist
        wsDest.Cells(i, Pricelist) = "RPIA.SIPF FV2"

     Next i

     MsgBox "Done"
```

essentially I want to copy the ID from "Wscopy" then and paste it down to last row then loop to next column in WsDest
this is what I expect. can anyone help me with this? thanks in advance

```
WsCopy worksheet
coulmn     B        E          H
        ABC123    ABC246    ABC345           

WsDEst worksheet

column
          B
         ABC123
         ABC123
         ABC123
         ABC123
         ABC246  
         ABC246 
         ABC246 
         ABC345
         ABC345
         ABC345
```

Comment: So what exactly are you having trouble with if you know how to copy data and find the last row?

Comment: I'm new to VBA so I'm not sure exactly how to write this code

Comment: You don't need to copy, just assign formula of destination equal to value of source. So  copyrng.Copy:   wsDest.Range("C" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues  becomes wsDest.Range("C" & lDestLastRow).Formula = copyrng.value